# anyone know when the method -photoLibraryDidChange called?

Tags: ios, frameworks, photo, phasset

i have test the method for many times, one thing for sure ,when the photo library changes ,the method was called. but after the change , the method would be called another twice( doesn't do anything ). do any one know why

```
2015-08-25 14:16:04.420 PhotoLibrary[25742:3293667] enter photoLibraryDidChange methods 
2015-08-25 14:16:04.445 PhotoLibrary[25742:3283461] something inserted. 
2015-08-25 14:16:17.199 PhotoLibrary[25742:3293667] enter photoLibraryDidChange methods 
2015-08-25 14:16:17.522 PhotoLibrary[25742:3293668] enter photoLibraryDidChange methods 
2015-08-25 14:17:04.762 PhotoLibrary[25742:3295134] enter photoLibraryDidChange methods 
2015-08-25 14:17:04.796 PhotoLibrary[25742:3283461] something changed. 
2015-08-25 14:17:18.056 PhotoLibrary[25742:3295135] enter photoLibraryDidChange methods 
2015-08-25 14:17:18.366 PhotoLibrary[25742:3295137] enter photoLibraryDidChange methods 
2015-08-25 14:18:22.915 PhotoLibrary[25742:3297134] enter photoLibraryDidChange methods 
2015-08-25 14:18:22.932 PhotoLibrary[25742:3283461] something changed. 
2015-08-25 14:18:34.275 PhotoLibrary[25742:3297133] enter photoLibraryDidChange methods 
2015-08-25 14:18:34.602 PhotoLibrary[25742:3297130] enter photoLibraryDidChange methods
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a delegate method which is called when there is a change in your camera roll content, i.e. if a photo was added or deleted. You need to make sure that your app is listening to the change: `[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] registerChangeObserver:self];`

Typically it is called in:

`- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` 

and is unregistered in:

`- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`

You need to import delegate `<PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver>` and you need to make sure your app has the permission to camera roll / photos.